# Why does Rexster show "titangraph[cassandra:null]" even though its connected?

Tags: gremlin, titan, tinkerpop, rexster

When I connect to Titan via the Gremlin console it says... `titangraph[cassandra:127.0.0.1]`

Rexster however says... `titangraph[cassandra:null]` even though I can browse the same set of vertices.

Why is this? Rexster makes it look as though it hasn't managed to connect.

Comment: I think we may need a few more information regarding your setup in order to answer you. Which version of Titan are you running? Are you running another local instance of Cassandra and if so, which version? What OS do you run Titan on? Which command did you type to start titan?

Comment: Mac OS, https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Downloads, Verson: Titan 0.4.1, Download link: Titan Server 0.4.1. Then I run it with 'titan.sh start'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message indicates that Cassandra did not start correctly.

Try starting Titan with the following:

```
titan.sh -c cassandra-es start
```

Have a look at `/conf` for additional configuration files.

Unless you *really* have to, I strongly suggest installing Titan 0.5.0 which comes with many useful features.

If you're starting with graph databases and Titan, I suggest trying with a single machine cluster or Berkeley DB as a storage backend. You may not need Cassandra yet.

You can also have a look at Titan/Aurelius official mailing list, I know the issue you're experiencing has been discussed there before: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/aureliusgraphs. You can search for resources there (see, for example, https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/bviB6E5TZ-A/TJxQv0U7WQEJ).

In the meanwhile, you can try Titan v0.5.0 in Node.js by connecting via HTTP with https://github.com/gulthor/grex (HTTP client). The recommended way of connecting to Rexster is via HTTP (TinkerPop 2.x) or WebSocket (in upcoming TinkerPop 3, which Titan will support in a future version).

Comment: Its still saying the same with the different start. If Cassandra didn't start correctly why am I able to connect to it via the Gremlin console and why does Rexster also allow me to browse it albiet with the 'null' status? I will give .5 a go. I was using .4 because Titan-Node requires it but seen as Titan-Node isn't working I have not a lot to lose.

Comment: Slightly updated answer with links to mailing list resources.

Comment: Aha... with 0.5 it says ' titangraph[cassandra:[127.0.0.1]]' in Rexster. So I suppose that is a satisfactory solution. :)

Comment: This Tinkerpop stack has got to be the coolest thing I've ever seen in tech.